# Latest version of Java SDK not showing on windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows, sdk, environment-variables, version

At the time of this post (11/19/2019), I downloaded Java JDK version 13.0.1 on my windows 10 machine. After the download, I modified the **Path** system variable on my machine to include this path "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin**" (without double quotes). I then modified my **JAVA_HOME** system variable to include this path "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1**". However, when I type "java -version" at the command prompt, this is what I get.

> java version "1.8.0_211"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)

Can someone please explain to me why my current java version from the command prompt is displaying the result above as opposed to java version 13.0.1? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you close and re-open your command prompt *after* you made the change to your environment variable settings?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes, and I would still get same result

Comment: It is possible that you have two JDK's on your Path. AFAIK Windows uses the first one... What is the output from `where java` (command prompt)?

Comment: @Campbell so initially I did have a prior JDK (version 12) on my path, however, I removed that JDK in replace of the newest version. Here is the output from "where java": C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe  
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall old JDK. I don't change anything when I install new JDK and I only choose new JDK within new project.

I have actually 3 versions of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the java_home and path using Command prompt.
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";

Note:
Once you set in command prompt, close and reopen cmd.exe for the changes to reflect.

Have a Happy programming !!! :-)

References:
https://www.codejava.net/java-core/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-java-using-command-line